# How to validate / fix an error in Certbot renewal cron

Tags: cron, ssl, letsencrypt, certbot

The whole day, I am fixing bugs in mainly TLS area, but this question is not specifically about TLS.

Well, I have one web server with a few web sites, each with its own SSL certificate.

But to the point, I managed to install Certbot version 0.19.0 on my Debian 9.2 like this:

1. Adding backports to the sources:

   ```
   deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
   ```
2. Installing newer version of Certbot from backports:

   ```
   apt-get install python-certbot-apache -t stretch-backports
   ```

Afterwards, I had to make some major adjustments to the renewal file, so it looks like this:

```
# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.10.2
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/pavelstriz.cz-0001
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pavelstriz.cz-0001/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pavelstriz.cz-0001/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pavelstriz.cz-0001/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pavelstriz.cz-0001/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
installer = apache
rsa_key_size = 4096
account = c3f3d026995c1d7370e4d8201c3c11a2
must_staple = True

[[webroot_map]]
pavelstriz.cz = /home/pavelstriz/public_html
www.pavelstriz.cz = /home/pavelstriz/public_html
```

I have managed to renew the `pavelstriz.cz` domain after this with:

```
certbot renew --dry-run
```

---

But what worries me is the daily Certbot's cron:

```
# /etc/cron.d/certbot: crontab entries for the certbot package
#
# Upstream recommends attempting renewal twice a day
#
# Eventually, this will be an opportunity to validate certificates
# haven't been revoked, etc.  Renewal will only occur if expiration
# is within 30 days.
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

---

I can't figure out if it works for real or how to run it successfully?

If I run:

```
/usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

in Bash, it says:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
The requested ! plugin does not appear to be installed
```

*I may have misunderstood those commands.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual command run by cron is:

```
test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

It starts by testing some files

```
test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system
```

which translates in

- does `/usr/bin/certbot` exist and is executable (`-x /usr/bin/certbot`)
- and not (`-a \!`)
- `/run/systemd/system` exist and is a directory (`-d /run/systemd/system`)

If the test succeeds, wait for a random number of seconds (`perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))'`), then try to renew the certificate (`certbot -q renew`).

However, on Debian 9, `systemd` is installed by default, which means that `/run/systemd/system` exists and is a directory, so the initial test fails and the renew command is never run.

The actual renewal is managed by a systemd timer defined in the file `lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer`. As of version 0.27.0-1; its content is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run certbot twice daily

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,12:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=43200
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

If cerbot is properly configured, you should probably find lines like

```
Nov  2 20:06:14 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Run certbot twice daily.
Nov  2 20:06:14 hostname systemd[1]: Started Run certbot twice daily.
```

in your `syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

> I may have misunderstood those commands.

Umm, maybe, a little :-)

This entry:

```
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

I cannot make heads or tails of. All you need is, in fact, something like:

```
0 */12 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew
```

Or, if you don't want any e-mails from `cron`:

```
0 */12 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If you run (as `root`) `certbot renew` you will see if you have configured 
things properly or not:

```
certbot renew
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/my.domain.org.conf
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cert not yet due for renewal

The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/fullchain.pem (skipped)
No renewals were attempted.
```

You can also use the `certificates` argument with `certbot` to display information about your certificates:

```
certbot certificates
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: my.domain.org
    Domains: my.domain.org
    Expiry Date: 2018-03-14 09:41:09+00:00 (VALID: 53 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/privkey.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```